# iPhone Mobile Safari meta viewport

Tags: html, ios, iphone, responsive-design, meta

when opening a website in iPhone Mobile Safari The full screen does not appear.

I tried this, but the problem still exists.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by full screen? Do you mean like you want it to be mobile friendly? or...

Comment: Yes, I  mean want it to be mobile-friendly

Comment: Could you please provide me with a screenshot of the glitch, Thanks!

Comment: Oh and there is no problem putting more than one thing in a single answer, rather thann creating 2 answers on the same question, info for next time

Answer (score -1):

Have you actually tried: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`? instead of all those over things that you added in.